# Переквалификация

Tags: работа

В данный момент работаю программистом в сфере web технологий, на молодую компанию. Мне 22 года, стаж 1 год - вся моя карьера =) Дополнительно подрабатываю фрилансом. Из образования только техникум по специальности ВМК. Нигде пока не учусь. Подумываю о том, чтобы в перспективе переквалифицироваться в менеджера проекта. Встал вопрос о выборе факультета ВУЗ'а. У меня выбор сейчас - продолжать учиться по специальности, получить бакалавра, либо бакалавриат закончить на менеджера. Вопрос такой - по какому профилю менеджмента получить высшее образование, чтобы успешно работать менеджером IT проекта? И смогу ли я, получив такое высшее продолжить карьеру программиста? Раньше я думал что привлекает программирование, и что сделаю на этом не плохие деньги. Теперь понимаю, что менеджером смогу зарабатывать больше денег. Удачная ли это будет комбинация, программист-менеджер? Как на это смотрят работодатели?

Comment: Лучше подумайте, как на Вас будут смотреть программисты (если вдруг кто-нибудь возьмет менеджером).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работодатели смотрят на это хорошо. Но надо учитывать два момента:

1. Чистым прогером выжить сложнее, чем чем прогером с дополнительными скиллами. Манагерство это нормально - это ясно. Но 1 год прогерства - это ни о чем. Ну хотя бы 5-6.
2. Важно здесь не сильно углубиться в предметную область, иначе кирдык. Скажем манагер по внедрению какой-нибудь системы бюджетирования Hyperion Pillar, с навыками программирования веб-плагинов к оной на ASP.NET - это практически вы обречены на пару-тройку компаний - больше просто нет на рынке.

Comment: На то и расчет, когда получу вышку, у меня как раз и будет стаж 5-6 лет.

Comment: Поступил по специальности. Решил, что менеджмент буду изучать на магистратуре.